# ToggleClass not wokiing

Tags: jquery

I´m using jQuery to make a div appear and disappear. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.button').on('click', function(){
                $('.text').toggleClass('hidden');
            });  
        </script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="button">show/hide test</div>
        <div class="text hidden">test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when i click on the div "button" nothing happens and the text is still hidden.

Comment: `.button` doesn't exist when you declare that in the header (hint: `$(window).load(function(){...})` or `$(document).ready(function(){...}))`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround your jquery in a document ready check like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('.button').on('click', function(){
                    $('.text').toggleClass('hidden');
                });  
            });    
        </script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="button">show/hide test</div>
        <div class="text hidden">test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you could simply move your jquery code at the end of your body tag so all elements it references will already exist, here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="button">show/hide test</div>
        <div class="text hidden">test</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.button').on('click', function(){
                $('.text').toggleClass('hidden');
            });    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can use a delegated event handler attached to an ancestor element that always exists like `body` or `document`. **Important Note:** It is advised to use `document` in preference to `body` as `body` has a bug to do with styling that means it may not receive mouse events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
        $('.text').toggleClass('hidden');
    });    
</script>
```

This works by listening for the event to bubble to the ancestor element (e.g. `document`), *then* applying the jQuery selector (i.e. `'.button'`) to the elements in the bubble chain, *then* applying the event handler function to the *matching elements that caused the event*. The end result is that the selector only has to match at *event time* and not when the event was *registered*. `document` always exists, so is a great place to connect the code.

Comment: Or simply move the script block below the markup, or simply use the delegated listener, as in my answer... `ready()` is not the only option.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Version

Change:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
```

to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {
```

---

### Long Version

You're not using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler correctly. The way you use it expects for the `.button` element to exist by the time the code runs, but it doesn't.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.

The correct syntax is something like `$('body').on('click', '.button', function() {`. See it here:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').on('click', '.button', function() {
    $('.text').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
</script>
<div class="button">show/hide test</div>
<div class="text hidden">test</div>
```

Comment: Is `document.body` guaranteed to be ready before `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` fires? I'd just combine both solutions you mentioned on your comment on @Canvas's answer :)

Comment: Hmm, I guess it depends on the browser, I think they all build head/body right away, but yes, the combination would be the best.